# How can i retrieve "extract" field from wikipedia api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mediawiki, wikipedia

This is the link which I have to parse it in Objective C:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=2&exintro=&titles=USA

If you clearly look at the link the word "USA" is actually going to change as per user requests.In the JSON information after pages key you can actually see a number before pageid. How can I access it? If that field is static I can access with that particular key. But it seems like that number is dynamic according to the user search. My aim is to access "extract" key. If I want to do that I have to go inside to that number which is a dynamic one. I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Under "pages" you are getting a dictionary with keys that are the same as the ids (just strings). It seems your question circles around the fact that you do not know these keys beforehand.

Once you extracted the `pages` dictionary, you can iterate through the keys like this:

```
for (NSString *idString in pages.allKeys) {
   NSDictionary *content = pages[idString];
   NSString *extract = content["extract"];
   // do something with extract
}
```

If you just want the any key or you are sure there is only one, you can instead create the content dictionary with

```
NSDictionary *content = pages[pages.allKeys.firstObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

One expression doing the same as Mundi's answer:

```
NSString *extract = 
     [[[array valueForKeyPath:@"query.pages"] allObjects].firstObject 
         valueForKey:@"extract"];
```